# Keep two files in sync on the same device

Tags: windows, sync, dropbox

I have a file that is my master library of all references (in BibTeX). When I start a new research project, I place a copy of that master library in the project folder to allow me to cite it. The problem comes when I make changes directly to either the master or the copy, and I forget to copy the changes.

I would use a symlink, but the files are stored in Dropbox, and [Dropbox doesn't play well with symlinks](http://www.paulingraham.com/dropbox-and-symlinks.html). I have the copy in git repository, but the master is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows, you might want to checkout Microsoft [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155).  I believe you can set a scheduled task for SyncToy to sync your files automatically on a given time.

I personally use [GoodSync](http://www.goodsync.com/), the software is more robust but that's not a free solution.

Answer (score 0):

FreeFileSync is another option if you want to keep files in sync.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [BOX](https://www.box.com)

here is what solution is suggested when using box at box [forum](https://support.box.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200267418-Sync-any-folder)

- Download Symlink Creator.
- Create a symbolic link folder for every folder you want to sync.
- Select Directory Symlink
- Link every source folder to a symlink folder.
- Put symlink folders in Box Sync folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bvkup2](https://bvckup2.com/). The beta is free. You can set up a scheduled job to continuously copy a changed file from one location to another location (your Dropbox?).